# Python write string of bytes to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, byte

How do I write a string of bytes to a file, in byte mode, using python?

I have:

```
['0x28', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0']
```

How do I write 0x28, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 to a file? I don't know how to transform this string to a valid byte and write it.

Answer (score 23):

Map to a `bytearray()` or `bytes()` object, then write that to the file:

```
with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(bytearray(int(i, 16) for i in yoursequence))
```

Another option is to use the [`binascii.unhexlify()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to turn your hex strings into a `bytes` value:

```
from binascii import unhexlify

with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(unhexlify(''.join(format(i[2:], '>02s') for i in b)))
```

Here we have to chop off the `0x` part first, then reformat the value to pad it with zeros and join the whole into one string.

Answer (score 11):

In Python 3.X, `bytes()` will turn an integer sequence into a bytes sequence:

```
>>> bytes([1,65,2,255])
b'\x01A\x02\xff'
```

A generator expression can be used to convert your sequence into integers (note that `int(x,0)` converts a string to an integer according to its prefix.  `0x` selects hex):

```
>>> list(int(x,0) for x in ['0x28','0x0','0x0','0x0'])
[40, 0, 0, 0]
```

Combining them:

```
>>> bytes(int(x,0) for x in ['0x28','0x0','0x0','0x0'])
b'(\x00\x00\x00'
```

And writing them out:

```
>>> L = ['0x28','0x0','0x0','0x0']
>>> with open('out.dat','wb') as f:
...  f.write(bytes(int(x,0) for x in L))
...
4
```