# Trying to access .gz file inside a .zip file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the following approach.

First name down the list of items in `.zip` file using `namelist()` and than use a specific item from the namelist and open it.

It's not working for me.

```
import zipfile
import gzip
nameofFile = raw_input("Enter File Name:")

def TEST():
   zf = zipfile.ZipFile(nameofFile, 'r')
   x = zf.namelist( )
   y = x[-4]
   print y

   with gzip.open(y, 'rb') as f:
       for line in f:
       if "Apple" in line:
       print "Fruit"
       break
TEST()
```

Following is the result of print y: `Log_File/Result.gz`

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what i'm doing wrong, getting the following error:

C:\Users\Sunil\Desktop>py test.py
Enter File Name:Log_File.zip
Log_File/Result.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
TEST()
File "test.py", line 13, in TEST
with gzip.open(y, 'rb') as f:
File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 34, in open
return GzipFile(filename, mode, compresslevel)
File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 94, in __init__
fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'Log_File/NodeDiagnostics.gz'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create zip file object from bytestring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910099/create-zip-file-object-from-bytestring-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

to open a `.gz` file stored within a `.zip` file:

```py
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip", "r")
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=zf.open("file.gz", "r"), mode="r") as f:
    # f.read(..)
    # for line in f: ..
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
with gzip.open(y, 'rb') as f:
```

you are opening a file outside the Zip. You need to do something like

```
gzip.GzipFile(zf.open(y))
```

Comment: Hello Rohana, thanks for reply, its giving me same error, is there any other method.