# How do you convert bytes into a zipped file in python? (originally a zip file) for GCP secret manager secrets?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

really need someones help here.

I am currently trying to store a zip file in GCP secrets manager and then retrieve the zip file in python.

```py
from google.cloud import secretmanager
import base64
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
PROJECT_ID = "project"
secret_id = "secret"
version_id = 1
name = f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"

response = client.access_secret_version(name=name)
bytes_returned = base64.b64decode(response.payload.data)

with open("my_zip.zip", "wb") as binary_file:
    # Write bytes to file
    binary_file.write(bytes_returned)
```

once I try and open the zip however it complains that the file is in the incorrect format.

When I download using gcloud commands everything seems to work

```bash
gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret "bi_cass_secure_bundle" --format "json" | \
  jq -r .payload.data | \
  base64 --decode > results_binary.zip
```

I have also tried the method explained here but with no luck
[Create zip file object from bytestring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910099/create-zip-file-object-from-bytestring-in-python)

Thanks in advance and I am sending you all some good karma

**extra notes**

Soo even if I have a valid zip file and write the bytes to another zip file I get the same error so it is something to do with the python library

```py
with open("valid.zip", 'rb') as file_data:
    bytes_content = file_data.read()


    with open("test_valid.zip", "wb") as binary_file:
        # Write bytes to file
        binary_file.write(bytes_content)
```

Comment: Any error messages? I just tried local folder, able to convert bytestring to Zip file in Python3.

Comment: Hi Rathish, what code are you using?

I just have a message from my OS when I try and open the file it says its invalid

Comment: I am able to write byte content to zipfile with the same code you have posted. Please share the complete error traceback to understand the issue.